# Javascript Arrays - How do they work internally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I wanted to know how javascript arrays work internally, I mean when for example you create a new array.

```
array = [1,2,3];
```

It's internally creating a new array: `array = new Array();`

and then calling `Array.push()` or similar?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just google these things.

Comment: Read the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax)

Comment: I did, can you point me to a good source? It would be much appreciated

Comment: Here is the best resource if you really want to know inner mechanics: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0. Start from [7.3.16 CreateArrayFromList (elements)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createarrayfromlist), then compare to [Array.prototype.push](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push). And you will know the answer to your question.

Comment: @dfsq Thank you for this source!

Answer (score 2):

The best resource to find out how javascript internals work is [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) itself.

In order to understand what happens internally when you do `array = [1, 2, 3]` you would need to read section [7.3.16 CreateArrayFromList (elements)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createarrayfromlist). Roughly what happens is that first Array object gets created, then each element gets set to this object with CreateDataProperty ([7.3.4 CreateDataProperty](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createdataproperty) section) (DefineOwnProperty) internal method.

Then you want to learn what exactly happens when you push element to array. You check [22.1.3.17 Array.prototype.push ( ...items )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push) section for this. There you will find out that it uses quite different algorithm, namely it sets specific property of an object ([7.3.3 Set (O, P, V, Throw)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw) section).

So the answer is no, creating array like `a = [1, 2, 3]` does not uses same mechanics to insert items as `push` does. The first one roughly *creates* new property on (newly created) array object, the `push` *sets* property to existing object.

Answer (score 0):

> and then calling Array.push() or similar?

**No**. As you can see in the below example that when `array` is initialized `push` (*overridden*) method is not invoked.

```js
Array.prototype.push = function(){ console.log("adding") };

var array = [1,2,3];

//console.log(array);
```

But, it is invoked when `console` statement is executed (after un-commenting the same).

Comment: Thank you for your response, that was the point I wanted to notice, but what I really wanted to know i what is happening internally. If I set array[0]= 1; what is really happening.

Comment: @Terry I posted comment with clear answer to this :)

Comment: @Terry *but what I really wanted to know i what is happening internally*  Check this link http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer

Comment: Or if you really want to get your hands dirty, -> https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/Source/JavaScriptCore  It's somewhere in there.. :)

Comment: *what is happening internally* - depends on the browser/javascript parser implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,2,3];
```

It doesn't call push but it's a simpler way to initialize an array when you know the elements in advance.

If you want to add another element you can do it in multiple ways like:

1) array.push(22); // adds integer 22 to the array

or

2) array[4] = 22; // adds integer 22 to the array at index 4

You can even do this:

array[20] = 22; // this will resize the array and keep all the uninitialized elements returns undefined. So array[10] is undefined, for ex.

If you want to know all the details about arrays explained in a simple way I recommend you the book: Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja. It has an entire chapter about arrays.

[https://www.amazon.com/Secrets-JavaScript-Ninja-John-Resig/dp/1617292850/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1519484868&sr=8-1&keywords=javascript+ninja](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617292850)